# Picky std::string char array constructor

Tags: c++, stdstring

Okay, I may be stupid, but I can't figure out what type the string constructor wants me to input as the second argument. This is fine:

```
unsigned char *cStringWannabe = new unsigned char[length];
baseStream.read((char*)cStringWannabe, length);

std::string *str = new std::string(cStringWannabe, cStringWannabe+sizeof(cStringWannabe));
```

But that overshots the size by one and doesn't make any sense.

I have no idea what to cast `sizeof(cStringWannabe)` to in order to please the constructor.

**EDIT:**

Okay, since I'm wrong here on so many levels, time to clarify things.

I want a function that will read a single character from a fstream, interpret that character as a length of the string and then read following (length) characters into a string object.

I'd prefer if function was given a pointer to existing string that it will then modify to contain the new data.

Comment: `sizeof(cStringWannabe)` is the size of a pointer. You probably don't want that. You probably don't want to `new` an `std::string` either, unless you're really into memory leaks.

Comment: `cStringWannabe+sizeof(cStringWannabe)` makes no sense. `cStringWannabe` is a pointer and `sizeof(cStringWannabe)` is it's size, and adding them together makes no sense here.

Comment: I'm reading from a fstream and am a rookie when it comes to c++.

I'm trying to create a function that, when called, will read a cha (indicating length), and then create a string with that many characters in it. Can I get a pointer to string and then modify an existing string?

Comment: If the data you `read`contains a 0-terminator, then you should not even have to add a second constructor argument for `std::string`. If the data contains no 0-terminator, then what DO you want the length to be?

Comment: Re your edit, post a hex dump of your input file.

Comment: First three chars of file spell out "7rg". For testing purpose, I hardcoded the length 3 into the function and skipped the length reading part. The goal was to create a string object "7rg".

Comment: How does hardcoding the length into the function help? Do you mean that the bytes in the file look like "37rg"? Can there be more than 9 characters in the string? It really is not hard to be more accurate when asking questions here.

Comment: First 4 bytes are 3 55 114 103.

Comment: What prevented you from consulting the documentation?

Comment: It said t_size, and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast it to anything to please the constructor. Using sizeof here is simply wrong, as it gives you the size of the pointer, not the length of the string. If anything, you want:

```
 std::string *str = new std::string(cStringWannabe, length);
```

and you almost never want to be allocating strings dynamically like that, so:

```
 std::string str(cStringWannabe, length);
```

and it's doubtful you want to read strings like this:

```
baseStream.read((char*)cStringWannabe, length);
```

Comment: I'll take a pointer to string into my function, and modify that.
I have an array of bytes that I want to read; array[0] is the length of the array, while the rest are characters of a string with that length. What's the fastest way to get that byte array (in form of a fstream) into a std::string?

Comment: @Karlovsky120: You can search for the answer to that, or keep reading your C++ book.

Comment: I figured it out. I just used the length of the char array in the constructor. I was in a mental gutten. I'd actually really like to delte this since.I don't think its useful to the community.